# jQuery's replaceWith() method changes PHP code to HTML comment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In a `click` event handler I would like to change a `div` element. In this element is also HTML and PHP code.

After the change the PHP code is in a HTML comment. What I can do to fix this?

[image]

Here is a short version of my code:

```js
$("#replaceCat1").click(function(){
  $("div.boxcontent2").replaceWith("<div class='boxcontent1'> <?php print_string('placehoder1', 'theme_'.$theme->name); ?></div> ");
});
```

Edit:

i design a theme. In this theme gives it 4 boxes with information from the backend. My php code is at the moment only a placeholder. later I include the backend php code. In my theme, gives a dropdown menu. In this gives 4 categories, when you select one, then I would like that the 3 of the 4 boxes switch die information and the design. That is the plan with the code.

The code comes from the .js file. It is better to load the code from a php file and include it with .load() ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? what for you need paste php code inside html on client side?

Comment: It's because your PHP code is not being processed on the server and is instead being treated as HTML. The HTML parser doesn't recognise a `<?php` tag so converts it to a comment. Presumably this code is from a `.js` file, if so that's your issue.

Comment: Is this part of code from an `.js` file or is it loaded into the browser via `.php` file as html content?

Answer (score 0):

If you want javascript to be able to dynamically include something that comes from php, then you will need to look into `AJAX`. Probably `jQuery's $.ajax()` function will be enough.

If you are simply wanting the text from PHP to appear once in the javascript, you will need to run the javascript through php.

Assuming that you actually have a php server an that your project is running on this server, a quick, ugly hack that will allow you to do this is to rename your `.js` file into a `.php` file, and `include()` it between a pair of script tags.

```
<script>
Include('filthy_hack.php');
</script>
```